# How to redirect to approval_url during Paypal call?

Tags: cakephp, paypal

When I got the second call response, it directly printed the state:created output but, how do I store information which directly printed itself?
I want to redirect the user or atleast send it to the rel=post URL but, when I save the output, it just gives the value - 1.

```
$URL = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json'
            , 'Accept-Language: en_US'
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $objRes = json_decode($response);
        $appId = $objRes->app_id;
        $accessToken = $objRes->access_token;
        $tokenType = $objRes->token_type;
        $ch2 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment');
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "Authorization:$tokenType $accessToken"
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->_generateJSON());
        $value = curl_exec($ch2);
      //$value = 1...
```

the value of $value is a number 1 so far...

Any guesses on how to redirect the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put RETURNTRANSFER and VERBOSE

```
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Done.

Though no one replied, if anyone comes across this issue, put it down on message. There are several ways to get this fixed.